# WordPress: Unsubscribe from comment notifications link in e-mail?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications, comments

I haven't been able to either program or find a plugin that gives me the ability to include an 'unsubscribe' link in comment notification e-mails (Wordpress website). 
The thing is everytime a new comment is posted on a post on my website, the author gets a notification via e-mail. I'd like a link in this e-mail that allows the author to unsubscribe from this mailing.

I know the complete comment notification function can be disabled in the WP backend, but it's more like a custom notification (yes/no) per post. Does anyone know of a plugin or function to write to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it is send by pluggable function, you can add a simple plugin (not theme) to override it. Code to be placed in plugin:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_notify_postauthor' ) ) {
  function wp_notify_postauthor () {}
}
```

Answer based on [this tutorial](http://www.stumiller.me/disable-wordpress-notifications-email-for-users-and-admins/)